# How to transform a grob object to a ggplot object? (for drawing outside axes)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'll quickly tell you how this question arose.

I wanted to draw stuff outside of the axes of a ggplot. Namely, polygons around x-axis tick mark labels. I found a way to do this by using the `annotation_custom()` and `grid::polygonGrob()` functions and turning off clipping. I guess my problem is that I am not too familiar with the objects yet. All I know is that after my manipulations, I get a grob object. That would be fine as it is, but I want to include it in a grid of plots using `cowplot`.

Here's my code:

```
# Required packages
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
require(cowplot)

# dput(data_B)

data_B <- structure(list(n = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("sample_1", 
"sample_2"), class = "factor"), fraction = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.24, 
0.45, 0.19, 0.045, 0.01, 0.005, 0.005, 0.04, 0.225, 0.53, 0.14, 
0.04, 0.02, 0), err = c(0.002, 0.01, 0.04, 0.06, 0.034, 0.009, 
0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.008, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.008, 0.004, 0
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

# The plot
panel_B <- ggplot(data=data_B,(aes(x=n,y=fraction,fill=sample)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fraction-err, ymax=fraction+err), 
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#f2a340','#998fc2'))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                     breaks=c(seq(min(data_B$n),max(data_B$n),by = 1)),
                     limits = c(min(data_B$n),max(data_B$n))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                     breaks=c(seq(0,0.6,by=0.1)),
                     limits = c(0,0.6)
  )

# Add polygons around tick mark labels (unfinished work)
panel_B <- panel_B + 
  annotation_custom(polygonGrob(x = c(-0.03,0.03,0),y = c(-0.09,-0.09,-0.02),
                                gp=gpar(col="black",fill=NA, lwd=3))
  ) +
  annotation_custom(polygonGrob(x = c(0.12,0.17,0.17,0.12),y = c(-0.09,-0.09,-0.03,-0.03),
                                gp=gpar(col="black",fill=NA, lwd=2))) 


# Turn off panel clipping
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(panel_B))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
panel_B <- grid.draw(gt)

# And a dummy version of a cowplot grid
plot_grid(c(),panel_B,nrow=2)
```

Additionally, I have the problem that the drawn polygons are not fixed, but tend to be dislocated when the plot proportions are changed. Maybe there's a totally different approach. Happy for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems; (1) you cannot use grid objects as input for plot arrangements for the cowplot operations and (2) the proportions of your polygonGrobs change as your device window resizes.

To fix the first problem, you could add the following line at the place in your code before `# Turn off panel clipping`, which will also turn the clipping off, but will still allow you to use the plot object with cowplot:

```
panel_B <- panel_B + coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

The second problem is likely a problem of units in which your polygons are defined. Since the x-axis itself has a weird height typically defined as `sum(2.75pt, 1grobheight)` it is quite unpredictable what would happen under all resizes. However, I find that if you define the polygons in 'native' units rather than 'npc', the results seem to be slightly more predictable.

```
# Add polygons around tick mark labels (unfinished work)
panel_B <- panel_B + 
  annotation_custom(polygonGrob(x = c(-0.03,0.03,0),y = c(-0.09,-0.09,-0.02),
                                gp=gpar(col="black",fill=NA, lwd=3), default.units = "native")
  ) +
  annotation_custom(polygonGrob(x = c(0.12,0.17,0.17,0.12),y = c(-0.09,-0.09,-0.03,-0.03),
                                gp=gpar(col="black",fill=NA, lwd=2), default.units = "native"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I also found a way to transform the grob back to a ggplot: `panel_B <- ggpubr::as_ggplot(gt)`

Comment: Where did you get this info on the x-axis height, `sum(2.75pt, 1grobheight)`? ty

Comment: If you use `ggplotGrob(panel_B)$height` you can see the heights of all elements in the gtable. The axis is the 8th element, as can bee seen from the t(op)/b(ottom) values of the `axis-b` entry in the layout: `ggplotGrob(panel_B)$layout`.

Comment: can you please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429978/r-converting-grob-objects-to-ggplot-plotly thanks

Comment: I know next to nothing about plotly I'm afraid.

Comment: leaving out plotly - do you know how to convert this object to ggplot?